# I have been trying to add firebase to my flutter app, and after adding all dependencies and libraries in main.dart the debugging process fails

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, debugging, flutter-hive

[Fatal Error] concurrent-futures-1.1.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] firebase-annotations-16.2.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] play-services-basement-18.1.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] play-services-tasks-18.0.2.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-annotations:16.2.0.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :firebase_core > com.google.firebase:firebase-common:20.4.2
> project :app > project :firebase_core > com.google.firebase:firebase-common:20.4.2 > com.google.firebase:firebase-components:17.1.5
> > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-annotations:16.2.0.
> > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-annotations/16.2.0/firebase-annotations-16.2.0.pom
> > Content is not allowed in prolog.
> Could not resolve androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.1.0.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :firebase_core > com.google.firebase:firebase-common:20.4.2
> > Could not resolve androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.1.0.
> > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/concurrent/concurrent-futures/1.1.0/concurrent-futures-1.1.0.pom
> > Content is not allowed in prolog.
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :firebase_core > com.google.firebase:firebase-common:20.4.2
> > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0.
> > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/18.1.0/play-services-basement-18.1.0.pom
> > Content is not allowed in prolog.
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.0.2.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :firebase_core > com.google.firebase:firebase-common:20.4.2
> > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.0.2.
> > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/18.0.2/play-services-tasks-18.0.2.pom
> > Content is not allowed in prolog.
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.0.2.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :firebase_core > com.google.firebase:firebase-common:20.4.2 > org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.6.4
> > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.0.2.
> > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/18.0.2/play-services-tasks-18.0.2.pom
> > Content is not allowed in prolog.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6m 39s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            404.8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

i have searched online but i could not get an answer about this

Comment: Can you share your pubspec.yaml file?